# JQuery: Change between datepicker functions if select value changes

Tags: jquery, function, dynamic, user-interface, datepicker

I have a page with a select list and two text boxes. The text boxes are linked with JQuery to a JQuery UI Datepicker.
I need a way to be able to change the functions of the text boxes such that, if the user selects an option from the select list, it uses a specific function, or if another options is selected, another function is used.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dates').change(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      if (value.indexOf('1') >= 0){
      $(function() {
          $('#datepicker_start').datepicker( {
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                    });
            $('#datepicker_end').datepicker( {
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
            });
        } else {
            $(function() {
                $('#datepicker_start').datepicker( {
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
                $('#datepicker_end').datepicker( {
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                });
            });
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you make your code readable if you want people to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the diff between two options only is showButtonPanel, maybe it is what you want

```
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker_start,#datepicker_end").datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'

    });
    $('#dates').change(function(){
         var value = $(this).val();
         var toShowButtonPanel = true; 
         if (value == ANYVALUEYOUDEFINED){
             toShowButtonPanel = false;  
         }
         $("#datepicker_start,#datepicker_end").datepicker("option","showButtonPanel",[toShowButtonPanel]);
    });


});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, though after testing I needed to change the if to "parseInt(value) == 1" because the original form did not work.

Comment: Yeah you get the point. Sorry I just copied ur code in that part.